# how to google search using dynamic xpath?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

I am trying to automate the Google Search for "Java" and when it provides a list, I want to select "java interview questions".
I tried using the below xpath, but the script is failing.

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role ='listbox']//li/descendent::div[@class='sbl1']"));
```

Below is my code for the same -

```
public class GoogleSearchTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver" , "C:/Users/User/Desktop/Selenium Drivers/chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Java");

        List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role ='listbox']//li/descendent::div[@class='sbl1']"));
        System.out.println("Total no of suggestions in search box::" +list.size());

        for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++) {
            System.out.println(list.get(i));

            if(list.get(i).getText().contains("Java Tutorial")) {
                list.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: "is failing" isn't a clear problem description. Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly!

Comment: Provided the simple solution with xpath, check and let me know.

Comment: @ChaitanyaMaligi You are missing the basic step to click on the button with text as **`Google Search`** ... How can you search without the _search results_?

Comment: @DebanjanB - list.get(i).click(); - have mentioned in the code

Comment: @ChaitanyaMaligi Nopes, your question heading was about _google search_ but your _code attempt_ and _accepted answer_ is about _Auto Complete_ / _Auto Suggestion_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using an invalid xpath locator and you need to give some delay before identifying & fetching the elements, try the below code :

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Java");
Thread.sleep(1000);

List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@role ='listbox']//li"));
System.out.println("Total no of suggestions in search box :: " +list.size());

for(int i=0; i<list.size();i++) {
        System.out.println(list.get(i));

        if(list.get(i).getText().trim().contains("java interview questions") || list.get(i).getText().trim().equalsIgnoreCase("java interview questions")) {
        list.get(i).click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Below is the screenshot which describes matching xpath:

[image]

Comment: hmm.. `"//ul[@role ='listbox]//li"` also appears to be an invalid xpath.  Trying it in the dev console returns `bach18.1.js:570 Uncaught Error: Z`a`logicalAnd`bool`string
    at kt (bach18.1.js:572)
    at U (bach18.1.js:573)
    at uo (bach18.1.js:767)
    at uo (bach18.1.js:570)
    at <anonymous>:1:1`

Comment: Please check my updated screenshot, I wondered why its not working for you?

Comment: Hmm.  It works when you search on the 'Elements' tab but not when you search on the 'Console' tab.  I wonder why? (downvote removed)

Answer (score 1):

No sure why you have to iterate through all the list items, when you can handle this with simple xpath. Here is the code that worked for me.

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("Java");
WebElement searchElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='suggestions-inner-container']//span[.='java salon']"));
System.out.println(searchElement.getText());
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;  
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();",searchElement);
Thread.sleep(1000); // just added time to make sure you will see the page navigation is successful.
driver.quit();
```

Answer (score 0):

simple. You have spelling mistake in the xpath. Its descendant and not descendant.
//ul[@role='listbox']//li/descendant::div[@class='sbtc']
Use Chropath, its shows you when the xpath is invalid

Answer (score -1):

That xpath appears to be invalid.  I think it would be easiest to find the elements by css using their class, like this:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector('li.sbct'));
```